# Androifd ListView ActionMode

Tags: android, listview

I have list view that is designated for chat ...

The Adapter can have either text, or attachments or text with links...

I need to implement selection mechanism on the list view such that

i) long press on any item should start the action mode

ii)If the action mode is on , subsequent clicks on the child views(attachments or links) should be discarded the chat item should be selected...

iii) If the Action mode is not on clicking on the  attachments should open the attachments....

Please help...

Comment: Clicking on the image view (child of list view)should be disabled if action mode(Used for deletion of messages) is on...

Comment: I have a list view that contains images and other attachments...If we click on the attachement  onTouch will be passed to imageView.. In case of some scenario (actionMode = on) I want imageviews to pass the touchevents to the parent so that list view can take the touch events...